# How to mirror an input field to another input field?

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent

I have an input field and multiple input fields, the original input field is the primary field that gets submitted.

So, I need to mirror one field to the main field.

I tried watching the `keyup` and `change` events but when the user pastes with the mouse it does not work, because the event is triggered before the user presses `paste` and not after it.

1. I am not sure that this is the best way to mirror two fields, so I am asking you if you have better methods of doing it
2. Is there an event that can be triggered after the paste is pressed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of triggering on key/mousevents, you could try using an "input" event on the input element you would like to mirror.

```js
const ogInput = document.getElementById("og")
const mirrorInput = document.getElementById("mirror")

ogInput.addEventListener("input", () => {
  mirrorInput.value = ogInput.value
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="og" />
<input type="text" id="mirror" />
```